# Refresh View when Tab becomes active

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios

I have a TabBarApplication for an iPad App, which is switching between two ModalViews (LoginForm / Memberarea) in one of the Tabs by checking Loginstatus. All works fine, but when I switch to another Tab of the Application and then switch back, no modal view is shown and the view don't refresh to check for status again.

Is there any way to keep the modal view on the TabView, even if user switches to another tab?
Or is it possible to refresh the View when its tab becomes active?

Would be great if someone can help me with this problem!

**EDIT: Problem solved!**

I solved it on my own. =)

The problem was: After switching to another TabView the modal don't show up, but is not dismissed. There was a error in my log displaying that the modal can't be viewed.

So to solve it I used the "viewWillDissapear" method and dismiss my modalView before switching Tabs, like this:

```
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

The Modal is dismissed, and after switching the View loads again and displays the deserved modalView. =)
Thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the refresh code you were talking about by implementing `viewWillAppear` in your view controller

Comment: I actually call it on viewDidAppear. viewWillAppear is never called in this situation. Dunno why..

Answer (score 0):

Call your code which clls modalview controller in viewwillappear method.